# Micronaut Repository - cannot inherit from final class

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, micronaut

I encountered an error with one of my repository classes where I'm using JdbcOperations. This issue happened when I updated Micronaut from version `3.5.0` to `3.6.0`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.myapp.repository.BulkUserMailSettingRepository$Intercepted cannot inherit from final class com.myapp.repository.BulkUserMailSettingRepository
```

```java
@Repository
class BulkUserMailSettingRepository(private val jdbcOperations: JdbcOperations)
```

I can compile it by adding the `@Singleton` annotation, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micronaut creates a subclass of your class and adds bean/query functionality there. You just need to make your class subclass-able by adding `open`:

```
@Repository
open class BulkUserMailSettingRepository(private val jdbcOperations: JdbcOperations)
```